# How to make a list in Python distinct based on a property of the class in the list?

Tags: python, list, unique, distinct

I have a list of instances from the same class, and I want to make my list distinct based on a property in the class. What is the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Here is some sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, classId, tag):
        self.classId = classId
        self.tag = tag

myList = []

myInstance1 = MyClass(1, "ABC")
myInstance2 = MyClass(2, "DEF")
myInstance3 = MyClass(3, "DEF")

myList.append(myInstance1)
myList.append(myInstance3) # note that the order is changed deliberately
myList.append(myInstance2)
```

If I want to sort my list now based on one of the properties in MyClass, I usually just sort it by key, and set the key using a lambda expression - like this:

```
myList.sort(key=lambda x: x.classId)
for x in myList:
    print x.classId

$ python ./test.py
1
2
3
```

Is it possible to use a similar method (lambda, map or similar) to make the list distinct based on the "tag" property? Also, if this is possible, is it the most "pythonic" way to make a list distinct based on a property of a class in that list?

I have already tried searching both SO and Google for topics on this matter, but all the results I found dealt with simple lists that only contained a numeric value and not a custom object..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [python dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
{x.tag: x for x in myList}.values()
```

For your example:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __init__(self, classId, tag):
...         self.classId = classId
...         self.tag = tag
...
>>> myList = [MyClass(1, "ABC"), MyClass(2, "DEF"), MyClass(3, "DEF")]
>>> uniqList = {x.tag: x for x in myList}.values()
>>> print [x.classId for x in uniqList]
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the property you wish to key on is immutable, you can use a dict:

```
d = {}
for x in xs:
    d[x.tag] = x
```

Now `d` will contain a single `x` per `tag` value; you can use `d.values()` or `d.itervalues()` to get at the `xs`.

NB. here last matching item wins; to have the first one win, iterate in reverse.

Comment: Once you also use filter() (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) which should be slightly faster because of the inline for-loop.

Comment: Thank you. This (use of dictionary) works, but is it the "best" way to achieve it? The solution suggested by pypat seems more pythonic.

Comment: @pypat: I guess you could, with the predicate adding previously-unseen values to the dict, or actually just a set: `s = set()`, then `filter(lambda x: False if x.tag in s else (s.add(x.tag) or True), myList)`. Thanks for the suggestion! The `for`-and-dict-based version feels simpler to me though, so I'd benchmark before switching.

Comment: the for and dict-based approach is absolutely simpler. I just mention filter() for the sake of completeness :)

Comment: @v3gard: I think it's very likely to be the simplest approach. To use `filter` here, you really need a mutating predicate (there's nothing specific to any particular element of the list which `filter` should use to include it or reject it -- instead, you need to compare different elements; that's not the typical use case for `filter`, although it can be made to support it in this instance, as demonstrated in the previous comment).

Comment: @MichałMarczyk: Thank you for the filter() sample code. This worked out great.